# Moving to Maven from GNUMake

Tags: java, maven-2, jflex, jflex-maven-plugin

I've been a long time user of the Make build system, but I have decided to begin learning the Maven build system. While I've read through most of the online docs, none seem to give me the analogies I'm looking for. I understand the system's lifecycle, but I have not see one reference to compile step dependencies. For example, I want to generate a JFlex grammar as part of the compile lifecycle step. Currently, I see no way of making that step a pre-compile phase step. Documentation seems to be limited on this. In general, the concept of step dependencies seem to be baked into Maven and require a plugin for any alteration. Is this the case? What am I missing, because currently the Maven build system seems very limited in how you can setup compilation steps.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do anything in Maven. It generally has a default way to do each thing, and then you can hook in and override if you want to do something special. Sometimes it takes a lot of Stack Overflowing and head scratching to figure it out.

There is even an official [JFlex Maven plugin](http://jflex.sourceforge.net/jflex-maven-plugin/usage.html).

Whenever possible, find someone who has made a Maven plugin do what you want. Even if it isn't 100% right, it may at least give you an idea on how to make maven do something.

**Minimal configuration**

*This configuration generates java code of a parser for all grammar files (*.jflex , *.jlex , *.lex , *.flex ) found in src/main/jflex/ and its sub-directories. The name and package of the generated Java source code are the ones defined in the grammar. The generated Java source code is placed in target/generated-source/jflex , in sub-directories following the Java convention on package names.
pom.xml*

```
<project>
  <!-- ... -->
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>de.jflex</groupId>
        <artifactId>jflex-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.0</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>generate</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
    <!-- ... -->
  </build>
  <!-- ... -->
</project>
```

This feels like the maven way to do things. Put your stuff in the right folders (src/main/flex), and this plugin will automatically build it into your project. If you want to [do fancier custom stuff, there are some options](http://jflex.sourceforge.net/jflex-maven-plugin/generate-mojo.html). but Maven is all about favoring convention over configuration.

Comment: Oh nice, it was that execution goal that got it working. I guess I'll need to go back and see exactly what that does. So the hook for plugins is adding an execution and that gets run during the lifecycle?

Comment: Evenrything in Maven is a plugin, even if you don't see it. For wanting to make a change, the first step is to take one of the built in plugins and change the configuration a little...  When the built in plugins don't do something, then you can go poke around with 3rd party plugins. If stll no luck, you can make your own :)

Answer (score 0):

To be frank I think that your current mindset maps much better to ant than to maven, and I would suggest starting with that.

Comment: Does that mean that Maven is not capable of adding additional build tasks to compile? I guess I could put the build steps in an ant file and have mvn just run that. However, that solution seems a bit ugly.

Comment: I did not say maven could not do it.  I said your mindset is closer to ant (coming from make) than maven.